# Https is not working for apache tomcat using public ip address

Tags: tomcat9

[Https is not working for apache tomcat using public ip address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCU5K.png)

Comment: <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
    secure="true" scheme="https" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
  <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
  <SSLHostConfig>
   <Certificate
    certificateFile="D:\keystore\sathgurusoft.pem"
    certificateKeyFile="D:\keystore\sathgurusoftprivatekey.pem" type="RSA" />
  </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

Comment: Edit on your question, not in comment.